# Express Multipart (Body Parser) - { [Error: unknown transfer-encoding] status: 400 }

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, http-headers

I am getting the error `{ [Error: unknown transfer-encoding] status: 400 }` from the express 3 module multipart. It sounds like the `TE` header should be getting sent - which it isn't. However, I have read that this header is incompatible with the `content-length` header, which is getting sent.

The following headers are getting sent:

```
{
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------092114122750368',
    'content-length': '6983',
    host: '******* ',
    accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'identity',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)'
}
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing this issue?

**edit1**

server code is given below:

```
var port = 80,
    express = require('express'),
    app;

app = express();

// support JSON, urlencoded, and multipart requests
app.use(express.json({
    limit: '50mb'
}));

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    limit: '50mb'
}));

app.use(express.multipart({
    uploadDir:'./uploads',
    limit: '50mb'
}));

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log(err);
});
```

There is obviously more code, but this is where the error actually occurs. The output of `req.header` is what I supplied above as JSON and the output of `{ [Error: unknown transfer-encoding] status: 400 }` was in the first line of this post. I originally added error callbacks after each `app.use` call but I found that it was `express.multipart` that was causing the issue.

Comment: Can you show the code? Where does the error happen?

Comment: are these the headers that are actually sent or just the ones you add? If you apply any transfer-encoding to the message it needs to be stated in the Transfer-Encoding header.

Comment: Server code added. The headers are all the headers that are being received - not ones that are added. I am not trying to apply any transfer encoding as I don't think it should be necessary given that I have defined `content-length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to add in `transfer-encoding: chunked` as this was how the data was being sent. The HTTP library we were using was adding in the `content-length` property, which is incompatible with the `transfer-encoding` property but it did not cause an issue with the server, so this is what we settled with.